# mongodb generate the same ObjectID when save data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm writing a forum, a user log in and publish posts, I use mongoose to save posts to the mongodb, I found that when a user publishes another post, the mongodb will generate the same ObjectID for all the posts the user publishes, and when the user log out and return, mongodb will generate new ObjectID.

here is my code:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
import db from './db'
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author:String,
    title:String,
    content:String,
    time:{}
 });
PostSchema.methods.savePost = function(post,cb){
    const date = new Date();
    const time = {
      date: date,
      year : date.getFullYear(),
      month : date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1),
      day : date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" +     date.getDate(),
      minute : date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate() + " " + 
  date.getHours() + ":" + (date.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes()) 
    };
    this.author = post.author;
    this.title = post.title;
    this.content = post.content;
    this.time = time;
    this.save(cb);
};
```

api:

```
postEntity.savePost(post,err=>{
        if(err){
            return res.status(500).end('server err')
        } else {
            console.log('publish successfully')
            return res.status(200).end('success')
        }
    })
```

here is all the code in my github: https://github.com/laoqiren/isomorphic-redux-forum/tree/master/server

Comment: I don't see enough code to pinpoint your problem, but one thing I'll point out is that you're wasting a lot of space setting up that savePost method.  The time stamp stuff can all be done by just setting the time stamps option in Mongoose, and the rest can be done by passing info to the constructor.

Comment: @Paul thanks , how about the github, all the code there

Comment: @Paul maybe https://github.com/laoqiren/isomorphic-redux-forum/tree/master/server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, yeah, the issue is that you're only creating one new post.

In `./api/addPost.js`, you do `const postEntity = new Post()`.  That will get called one time (the first time the file is required or imported) and then the same postEntity will be used on all subsequent uses.

instead, you can write it like so:

```
const jwt = require("jwt-simple");
import Post from '../Models/post';

export default function(req,res,next){
    const token = req.body.access_token;
    let name;
    if(token){
        try{
            var decoded = jwt.decode(token,req.app.get('jwtTokenSecret'));
            if(decoded.exp < Date.now()){
                return res.end('token expired',401);
            }
            name = decoded.name;
        } catch(err){
            res.status(401);
            return res.send('no token');
        }
        const post = new Post({
            title: req.body.title,
            content: req.body.content,
            author: name,
            discuss: []
        }); 
        post.save(err => {
            if(err){
                return res.status(500).end('服务器错误')
            } else {
                return res.status(200).end('发表文章成功')
            }
        })
    } else {
        return res.status(401).end('没有登录')
    }

}
```

As a side note, you probably should pull your jwt expiry checking out of that route handler and into its own middleware (or better yet, adopt Passportjs), for better reuse.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm sorry for answering you so late because I'm busy with going back to school.